# Compiling SystemC library in Mingw32

Tags: c++, mingw, systemc

I have been trying to compile systemC library in Mingw32 and I am getting an error when I run the "configure" command which says that the architecture is not supported. Anyone out there solved this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If they don't support MinGW then the only thing you really can do is contact the developers and ask them if they have any plans to support it (or hopefully at least supply a work around).

However, it is entirely possible that there is a valid reason why MinGW isn't supported.

Comment: Don't bet on that... OSCI is very hesitant to touch its code. They are not a tools organization, but a standards org with an example implementation.  If you want this support, you can buy from a number of EDA vendors for some thousands of dollars (or maybe more, no idea of pricing).

Answer (score 1):

The Code::Blocks IDE has a helpful feature for importing Visual C++ sln files.The resulting Code::Blocks project can then be built using MinGW32.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS)?  It's a MinGW project designed specifically for building applications that depend on Unix command-line tools (e.g., configure) in a Windows environment.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to solve this yourself. I have tried it, and failed to succeed fully.

There are patches floating around on the [SystemC help mailinglist](http://www.systemc.org/Discussion_Forums/helpforum/), but they rely on precise obscure MSYS versions and thus do not work on Windows Vista.

In general, there is no real value in my opinion to using MinGW for SystemC. To compile SystemC natively on Windows, just pick up the free MS Visual Studio C++ Express compiler and use that. To compile it in command-line style, use cygwin.

MinGW is not supported currently by OSCI, and don't expect it to be anytime soon. The SystemC 2.2.0 kernel is supposed "stable" and will not be updated. Supporting new hosts is properly the domain of EDA tool vendors like Synopsys, Mentor, Cadence, CoWare, Forte, etc.  If you need MinGW support, the best bet is to go buy a commercial solution where someone has put that effort in.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the MSYS platform, where you are running configure, is not supported.
Use **MSYS** with mingw32 as **target** platform manually.
Start an MSYS shell by executing **msys.bat** in your MSYS installation folder (typically C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\msys.bat). Then cd to the SystemC folder. Configure your build using the following commands:

```
mkdir obj
cd obj
../configure --target=mingw32
make
```